# What is the correct verb to describe a file included with an email conversation?

Tags: british-english, past-participles

Is it correct to use "**attached**" when a file is included in a corporate Email?.

One of our customers has repeatedly requested us to send them some records and we would always respond in the Email stating "Kindly find the ***attached*** documents/records", but is this a valid use?

If not, what other verbs should I use to describe a file included with an email? What would native speakers say?

Comment: I've made your question a little bit more generic, in order to get better answers. We've had questions about files attached to emails before, and it would be nice to get a more generic answer that we can then point other learners to when they have a question about files included with emails.

Comment: @Matt Hi Matt, Your edit is perfect. Expecting possible answers for the same

Comment: note: *attached* is an adjective in this sentence, not a verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "attached" is perfectly valid English for describing files included in an email.

You can also refer to the things that were attached as "attachments". This means that the following sentence is valid: "The attachments were not attached.".

You can see examples of "attachment" and "attached" in the Wikipedia article [Email attachment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_attachment).

Comment: "Attachments to" emails are analogous to the increasingly old-fashioned "enclosures in" so-called "snail  mail".